# Reporting Services - get previous column value if current is NULL

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I am trying to reduce the size of the data a `T-SQL` query returns to the `Reporting Services`. For example, let's say we have the following row set:

```
ID  Country City
1   Germany Berlin
2   Germany Berlin
3   Germany Berlin
4   Germany Berlin
5   Germany Hamburg
6   Germany Hamburg
7   Germany Hamburg
8   Germany Hamburg
9   Germany Berlin
10  Germany Berlin
```

It can be transform easily to this:

```
ID  Country City
1   Germany Berlin
2   NULL    NULL
3   NULL    NULL
4   NULL    NULL
5   NULL    Hamburg
6   NULL    NULL
7   NULL    NULL
8   NULL    NULL
9   NULL    Berlin
10  NULL    NULL
```

As I may have thousands of thousands of duplicated values (and hundreds of columns), I know that transforming the data using `NULLs` like this reduce dramatically the size of the returned data.

Is it possible, to implement a formula, which get's the previous row column value, if the current one is `NULL`?

I want to test if it will be faster to just render huge data or to work with smaller data but apply such expression.

Comment: I think it cannot be done by using an expression with built-in functions. It can be done by using custom code but taking in account you have hundreds of columns it will impact the processing time. While you reduce the data retrieval time you increase the processing time.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use Group BY

```
SELECT Min(Id) as min, Max(ID) as max,Country,City 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY Country,City
```

Or

```
SELECT count(Id) as rowRepeatNum,Country,City 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY Country,City
```

The first approach would work if your Ids were sequential for this although I'm not sure if the Id is important.

The second way can give you an number to loop down to generate repeat rows in your application fairly quickly and return significantly less rows.

Can give me more info on your use case?